# AJAX doesn't wait for fpdf to end the creation of the file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fpdf

I click a button in HTML and it triggers a JavaScript function `savePDF`.

I use AJAX to save data into a DB.

I wait for the function 1 to be finished putting this code:

```
url: "InsertSelectData.php",

dataType: "html",
async: true,
success: 


event.preventDefault();
$.when(func01).then(func02);
```

function 2: I use the same vars from HTML page to generate fpdf but is not creating a pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have inserted the 2nd ajax inside the Success part of the first one.